# What to do about noise coming from Sink drain pipe

Tags: drain, water-damage, noise, rain, sounds

My sink's outlet pipe is connected to a drain pipe which connects with building outlet pipe.

The rain that comes from roof top is carried by a pipe which is connected with the building outlet pipe.

Build outlet pipe goes like 100 yard before emptying into the near by canal.

So whenever there's a heavy rain I can hear noise coming from the drain pipe of Sink.

Should I be worried ?

Please check out the AV [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13RnkbzKHMumtSKENlpDMx1nckZlrILM_/view?usp=sharing). You can hear the noise.

I was thinking to keep a P-Trap for Sink drain but when I listen to the sound I feel that the water in the P-Trap might get sucked and become waterless ?

During rainy season , water level in the canal is bit higher than building outlet pipe.

Please share if there are any industry standards in this scenario.

Comment: Your location in the world might help.  Most of the stuff you mention would not be allowed here.  We must have P-traps for all sinks/tubs and draining to a canal is a no-no.

Comment: @crip659.. It's South Asia. The canal is actually a drainage canal. it's mostly drainage canal .. meaning when it rains the water gets collected in this and this water goes out of town.

Comment: P-traps are use to keep sewer gases from coming up the sink drains.  It won't hurt to put one in.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to put p-Trap anyways. But I'm wondering , the noise you heard in the AV right ? I think would it not empty the p-trap ? Should I also be doing anything else ? The possibility of getting any sewer gas is bit less because it's not connected with any underground sewage system ..the grey water simply goes to open drainage canal .. just saying

Comment: Should I be worried about the noise and do something.. I don't want he pipes to get de-pressurised ?

Comment: I can't play the AV, but the noise is probably just water running down.  The drain pipes are not pressurized.  They do let air in from on top so draining water does not create a vacuum.

Comment: Thanks , that helps